# Count of nodes which do not have a label?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

How do I use kubectl to get K8S nodes  which do not have any labels?
Also , how do I fetch K8S pods which do not have any labels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to leverage kubectl `-o` flag and go-template output:

```
kubectl get nodes -o go-template='{{range .items }}{{if .metadata.labels }}{{else}}{{printf "%s\n" .metadata.name}}{{ end }}{{end}}
```

This command will show only nodes which do not have any labels. The same can be used for pods:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o go-template='{{range .items }}{{if .metadata.labels }}{{else}}{{printf "%s\n" .metadata.name}}{{ end }}{{end}}'
```

Comment: I could get the pods with labels using jsonpath by entering the following
  
 `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{.items[?(@.metadata.labels)].metadata.name}'`
  
  But the following did not work     
  `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{.items[?(!@.metadata.labels)].metadata.name}'`

Comment: Kubectl jsonpath parser does not support negation:https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go/blob/master/util/jsonpath/parser.go#L148 , you have to use go-template as per my example in order to do what you want

Answer (score 17):

For those who want to find resources without a specific label, no matter its value:

```
kubectl get ns --selector='!label_name'
```

Answer (score 8):

The first answer works but you can also use the following

`kubectl get nodes -l '!label_name'`

Answer (score 3):

according to the official [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/labels/) I dont think there is a way of doing that, but you can do something like that with the negation of equality:

```
kubectl get nodes --selector=kubernetes.io/hostname!=node_host_name
```

basically you can select everything that doesn't have a particular label, you can also chain selectors

More reading: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific way to check for no labels in general without listing every possible label. You would have to do this client side.

Answer (score 0):

here the client side jq query for it.

```bash
kubectl get nodes -o json| jq '.items[].metadata|select( has("labels") == false )|.name'
```

Here as bonus solution to find object (secret in this example) without any **annotation** nor **labels**

```bash
secretNoAnno=$(kubectl  get secret -o json| jq '.items[].metadata|select( has("annotations") == false )|.name') 
secretNoAnnoClean=$(echo "$secretNoAnno" | tr -d '"')
kubectl  get secret $secretNoAnnoClean -o json| jq '.items[].metadata|select( has("labels") == false )|.name'
```

Answer (score -1):

there is no way to check the nodes/pods that dont have labels. Instead what you can do is check for nodes/pods for specific label

follow the below steps

add label mylabel=k8s

```
master $ kubectl get no
NAME      STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
master    Ready     master    51m       v1.11.3
node01    Ready     <none>    50m       v1.11.3
master $
master $
master $ kubectl label nodes node01 mylabel=k8s
node/node01 labeled
master $
master $ kubectl get no -L mylabel
NAME      STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION   MYLABEL
master    Ready     master    52m       v1.11.3
node01    Ready     <none>    52m       v1.11.3   k8s
```

list nodes that has label mylabel=k8s

```
master $ kubectl get no -l mylabel=k8s
NAME      STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
node01    Ready     <none>    53m       v1.11.3
master $
```

list the nodes that doesnt have label mylabel=k8s

```
master $ kubectl get no -l mylabel!=k8s
NAME      STATUS    ROLES     AGE       VERSION
master    Ready     master    53m       v1.11.3
```